# scipy curve_fit and local minima: get to global minima as fast as possible

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, least-squares

my problem at hand: I am using `scipy` `curve_fit` to fit a curve (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) but in many occasions, the parameters estimated for such curve refer to one of the local many **"local"** minima and not **"global"** minimum. Now this is to be expected given how `curve_fit` was designed. Still, I really need my global minimum.

In order to find it, my initial hunch would be to multiply initial starting points, run multiple `curve_fit` instances and choose the one with the lowest fit error but I would suffer from a number of biases in my personal initial guess estimates (also potentially the number of combinations could be considerable and this would be detrimental to performance).

Do you happen to know better, faster and/or methodologically sounder methods on how to proceed? (they do not need to pass for least squares, I can build ad hoc stuff if necessary)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple possible approaches. One would be to do a "brute force" search through your parameter space to find candidate starting points for the local solver in `curve_fit`.  Another would be to use a global solver such as differential evolution.  For sure, both of these can be much slower than a single `curve_fit`, but they do aim at finding "global minima".  Within `scipy.optimize`, these methods are `brute` and `differential_evolution`, respectively.  It should be noted neither of these is *actually* global optimizers, as they both require upper and lower bounds for the search space of all parameters.  Still, within those boundaries, they do attempt to find the best result, not just a local minimum close to your starting values.

A common approach is to use `brute` with medium-sized steps for each parameter, then take the best ten of those and use Levenberg-Marquardt (from `leastsq`, as used in `curve_fit`) starting from each of these.  Similarly, you can use `differential_evolution` and then refine.

You might find `lmfit` (https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py) helpful, as it allows you to set up the model once and switch between solvers, including 
`brute`, `differential_evolution`, and `leastsq`.   Lmfit also makes it easy to fix some parameters or place upper/lower bounds on some parameters. It also provides a higher-level interface to model building and curve-fitting, and methods to explore the confidence intervals of parameters.

Comment: Differential evolution can find parameters outside the given bounds, those are to seed the genetic algorithm populations and the algorithm is not restricted to evolve solutions only within the bounds.

Comment: @JamesPhillips I could be wrong, but I was under the impression that the version of differential evolution in `scipy.optimize` did require and enforce bounds...  Guess that should be clarified....

Comment: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/optimize/_differentialevolution.py has the source code.

Comment: I have reviewed the source code I linked to and made some simple tests. You are correct that scipy's version of Differential Evolution will not return parameters outside of the given bounds. Interesting, very interesting. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: @JamesPhillips thanks for verifying.  This is something that has long bothered me about the scipy version.  I take it that your version does not impose this boundary?  Should we consider adding your implementation to lmfit?

Comment: I find it odd that if bounds are [-1, 1] and a correct parameter value is 1.1, the scipy version cannot give the correct value even if "polish=True" is used as the bounds are passed to curve_fit()! There is no option for disabling this, most curious. My pyeq3 version of DE does not impose bounds directly, although "brick wall" bounds can be used, my DE implementation does not impose bounds. The library's version is optimized for performance, as a major drag is the generation of random numbers - I create a very large list of random numbers once and use it as a curcular buffer. Works great.

Comment: I took a look at those and they would serve my purpose if not for the fact that they would take a considerable amount of time to run. i'll try to reverse engineer my problem by trying to guess the set of initial points per function by identifying some "main" output results. the initial setup might not be quick but it will enormously improve performance at scale. p.s.: thank you all for your input